# Rest Api in joomla

Tags: web-services, rest, joomla, joomla2.5

i want to implement restful api in joomla, but didn't get good tutorial, I'm looking for good tutorial. Are there any suggestions for rest api implementation in joomla?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this component.  If your looking for the quickest path to implementing a restful service install it.  If your looking to hand roll your own solution, this would be a good extension to reverse engineer or fork on github.

http://techjoomla.com/rest-api-for-joomla